# What is the Tensorflow equivalent of looking up dictionary?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following code:

```
def map_per_image(class_index_array):
    def index_to_label_f(index):
        index_to_label = {0:label_Vehicles, 1:label_Roads, 2:label_None}
        #print(index.eval())
        label = index_to_label[index]
        return label
    translated = tf.map_fn(index_to_label_f, class_index_array)
    return translated
```

Outside of Tensorflow environment, using ordinary map it would have worked. But the value of the argument `class_index_array` is a tensor, thus is its element, `index` also tensor.

I need somehow to convert the tensor `index` to an int value, in order to look up the dictionary. I tried `index.eval()` but got an error:

```
ValueError: Operation 'map_8/while/map/while/TensorArrayReadV3' has been marked as not fetchable.
```

Without such conversion, I would get a different error due to using a tensor value to look up the dictionary:

```
KeyError: <tf.Tensor 'map_9/while/map/while/TensorArrayReadV3:0' shape=() dtype=int32>
```

I wonder what's the proper way to express my above implementation logic in Tensorflow execution (session) environment?

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316250/tensorflow-dictionary-lookup-with-string-tensor

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Yes, it solved my problem. I had to think and code in tensor not iterating over array elements.