# tensorflow: how to dynamicly select tensor from feature dict

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say I'm using dataset + feature_columns to generate feature tensor, 
and i want to do the operations in comments below to select one tensor in the feature dict by another `indicator` scalar tensor:

```
def _parse_function(example_proto):
  features = {"f_0": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int32, default_value=0),
              "f_1": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int32, default_value=0), 
              "f_2": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int32, default_value=0), 
              "indicator": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int32, default_value=0),}
  parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)

  # what i want to do:
  # i = parsed_features['indicator']
  # parsed_features["f"] = parsed_features["f_{}".format(i)]

  return parsed_features

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)

# f is selected from [f_0, f_1, f_2]
feature_column = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="f")
```

I wonder how to implement this in tensorflow.

Comment: You can check out lookup tables ([relevant stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316250/tensorflow-dictionary-lookup-with-string-tensor/35321717)), or restructuring your input data so that the f_0, f_1, f_2 are in a single array. In the latter case, the indicator value can be used as an index.

Comment: @KathyWu it seems that lookup table can not have tensors as values, and 'indicator' is a tensor, which can not be used to index a list

Comment: I'll post an answer with examples -- it is possible to use tensors to index a list (if that list is a tensor), and using tensor as keys/values in a lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. Examples for using a lookup table and restructuring the input data are below.

---

## Lookup Table

Create a [HashTable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup/HashTable) from the parsed example, and use `table.lookup` to get the desired feature.

**Runnable example:**

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create example proto
def _int_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value))

e = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
  "f_0": _int_feature([10]),
  "f_1": _int_feature([20]),
  "f_2": _int_feature([30]),
  "indicator": _int_feature([1])}))
e_proto = e.SerializeToString()

def _parse_function(example_proto):
  features = {"f_0": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=0),
              "f_1": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=0),
              "f_2": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=0),
              "indicator": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=0)}
  parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)

  # Create HashTable
  keys = ["f_0", "f_1", "f_2"]
  values = [parsed_features[k] for k in keys]
  table = tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable(
      tf.contrib.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(keys, values),
      default_value=-1)

  # Add lookup value to the parsed_features dictionary
  indicator_key = "f_" + tf.as_string(parsed_features["indicator"])
  parsed_features["f"] = table.lookup(indicator_key)

  return parsed_features

features = _parse_function(e_proto)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.initialize_all_tables())
  print(sess.run(features))
```

Outputs:
`{'indicator': 1, 'f_0': 10, 'f_1': 20, 'f_2': 30, 'f': 20}`

---

## Restructuring input data

Combine the features into one matrix, and use the indicator to index into the feature matrix.

**Runnable example:**

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create example proto
def _int_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value))

e = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
  "all_features": _int_feature([10, 20, 30]),
  "indicator": _int_feature([1])}))
e_proto = e.SerializeToString()

def _parse_function(example_proto):
  features = {"all_features": tf.FixedLenFeature([3], tf.int64),
              "indicator": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=0)}
  parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)

  indicator_key = parsed_features["indicator"]
  parsed_features["f"] = parsed_features["all_features"][indicator_key]

  return parsed_features

features = _parse_function(e_proto)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(features))
```

Outputs:
`{'indicator': 1, 'all_features': array([10, 20, 30]), 'f': 20}`

Comment: the code works! but i found that the first approach only works when i have only one example as the HashTable will not be updated in a training loop, it always returns the feature value of the first example it meets.

Comment: My guess is that tables don't work well with dataset, especially if a table must be created for each example in the dataset (rather than a single master lookup table). I would recommend going with the second method.